# Difficult to get the element out of this array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

In my Laravel application, I try to access the text within the array within only one element, but it gives me error.

```
$account_id = DB::select('select id from chart_of_accounts where type =\'Expense\' LIMIT '.$request->account_id.',1;');
return $account_id[0];
```

The error message:

```
The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "object" given.
```

If I return the whole thing:

```
return $account_id;
```

Output:

```
[{"id":19}]
```

I do not know how can I convert this array into a single string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The laravel `DB::select()` function returns an array of objects, as mentioned in the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/database#running-queries):

> The `select` method will always return an `array` of results. Each result within the array will be a PHP `StdClass` object, allowing you to access the values of the results

You will need to access the `id` attribute of the object:

```
$account_id = DB::select('select id from chart_of_accounts where type =\'Expense\' LIMIT '.$request->account_id.',1;');
return $account_id[0]->id;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use this query method

```
$account = DB::table('chart_of_accounts')
                ->select('id')
                ->where('id', $request->account_id)
                ->where('type', 'Expense')
                ->take(1)
                ->first();

return $account->id;
```

**but for offset :**

```
$account = DB::table('chart_of_accounts')
                ->select('id')
                ->where('type', 'Expense')
                ->offset($request->account_id)
                ->take(1)
                ->first();

return $account->id;
```

Comment: is there any way to translate SQL syntax Limit(1,2) into query builder?